# SAS how concatenate variables from different observations in 1 observation by group

Tags: dataset, sas

i have students with different address, 1 in each observation and i want to put all the addresses in 1 observation by student

i have this:

```
data students;
input  name : $50.  address $50.;
datalines;
Ron St Jeremy
Ron Central Market
Edna St Thomas
John Av. Washington
John St Jeremy
Ron  Dolphin 541
;
run;
```

I want this dataset:

```
Name  address
Ron   St Jeremy, Central Market, Dolphin 541
Edna  St Thomas
John  Av. Washington, St Jeremy
```

How can i do that?

Comment: Do the strings have to be concatenated in any particular order?  For example, is "Central Market, Dolphin 541, St Jeremy" an acceptable result for Ron?

Comment: no, but only if i have a student who have in their addresses "St Thomas, Central Market" and other with "Central Market, St Thomas", SAS will take like differents even if the addresses are the same but backward

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would something like this suffice:

```
data students;
input  name : $50.  address $50.;
datalines;
Ron St Jeremy
Ron Central Market
Edna St Thomas
John Av. Washington
John St Jeremy
Ron  Dolphin 541
;
run;

proc sort data = students;
          by name;
run;

data want;
length cat $250.;
   do until (last.name);
      set students;
        by name notsorted;
      cat=catx(', ',cat,address);
   end;
   drop address;
run;
```

Without an indicator of address order there's no way of creating a specific logical rule behind it.

EDITED ANSWER @user3142441 is quite right, an sort is needed first - missed this out when writing up the answer.

Comment: Um, this doesn't produce the example desired output.  Ron comes out on two rows.

Comment: yes, you are right but i used a proc sort by name before, and it works.

Answer (score 2):

If order is not important (not sure I understood your comment) then you could do:

```
proc sort data = students out = students_srted;
 by name;
run;

data concat;
 set students_srted;
 by name;
 retain concat_address;
 if first.name then do; concat_address = address; end;
  else do; concat_address = concat_address || address; end;
 if last.name then do; output; end;
run;
```

This will concatenate your names, however makes no allowances for duplication in your data or ordering for which you would need to provide more detailed info